# Establishing via code whether console should be saved to a file (and the name of such file)

Tags: c++, c, logging, console

I know that when a program is executed in the console, one can specify an output file where the console can be saved. For instance, in Windows:

```
C:\>myprogram.exe > output.txt
```

However, is there a way to establish via code, i.e. programatically: 1) whether the console should be saved to a file; and 2) the name of the file to which the output should be saved, if any.

I know that I can of course use `fprint` or `std::cout` to print each string to a file the same I can do to the console. But for performance sake, I would like to know if it is possible to establish via code that the entire console should be saved to a file.

Comment: Are you wanting to just add output to the existing program or set up the output as you write? It would be simple to make your own method for every time you use console.write and have that method use a bool value set at runtime to output to file or not.

Comment: Note that in Windows if there is some output you want directed and some you always want sent to console, you can use the `conio.h` functions, which (unlike the `stdio.h` functions) do not get redirected. Such as `_cprintf` and `_putch`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can write code like this:

```
  int main( int argc, char * argv[] ) {
      if ( argc > 1 ) {
         // there is a filename on the command line
         ofstream ofs( argv[1] );       // open named file
         // do something with ofs
      }
      else {
          // do something with standard output
      }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess what you mean is that I could add an extra condition to that `if condition` you have there, in order to determine whether anything at all should be printed or not. But that is not a real solution, because then I would have to either print to both console and file, or none. I would not be able to choose programatically between printing only to the console or to both console and file. Also, it would still depend on whether a file name was passed to the application.

Comment: You have to give the application something to go on. At minimum this would be a filename, or no filename in the case of output redirection. Also, if you want to display stuff on the console and put it in a file, the simplest thing to do is to use an OS facility such as the `tail` command. But it's really not clear what you _do_ want.

Comment: @NeilButterworth How? You mean to log to file and run something like `tail -f output.txt` in parallel? `tail` is good for viewing log files to see just last lines but if I understand it correctly, he needs to log to console or to file or to both. so `myprogram.exe | tee output.txt` logs to output.txt and also to console.

Comment: @j123 It's, IMHO,  more flexible to use tail in a separate window. But this is getting off the topic.

Comment: @NeilButterworth It depends. He does not specify the purpose so we can just imagine his use case. If you have already running application using just log file, it is rally only the solution to use `tail`, but if you are starting new command, it it less work to use `tee`. If you need to make "shortcut" to start your appliaction and log to both file and console, it is much more practical to use `tee`.

Comment: @j123 There is one very good reason not to use tee - if you kill the window that the tee is being executed in, you also kill the monitored process, which isn't so for tail in a separate window. One of my colleagues once did this for a trading server process during high-volume trading, and had to take a couple of days off for stress related issues once he had fixed everything up again, which took many hours. If you know that whenever you see a log you can always safely kill that window, things are a little less stressful. But, as I said, this is really OT.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`dup2`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/dup2) function (in windows [`_dup2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/dup-dup2)). It can solve the problem to log to the console exclusively or log to the file exclusively. This is not a solution to log to both.

You can use some logging library (log4cxx, log4cpp, Boost.Log, QDebug, etc.) They should have abilities you need - e.g. log to both console and file.

### Solution with `dup2`/`_dup2`:

You can open new file, then call `dup2` to exchange stdout with that opened file. It can work with c++ streams but I did not try it.

Relevant part of Microsoft example (all checks removed, pleas se [original example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/dup-dup2). I don't have Windows so I can't verify it.)

```
#include <stdlib.h>  
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <io.h>  

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    FILE *DataFile;
    fopen_s( &DataFile, "data", "w" ); // open file "data" for writing
    _dup2( _fileno( DataFile ), 1 ); // exchange "standard output/console" with file "data"

    printf("this goes to 'data' file'\r\n"); // print to standard output, but it will be saved to "data" file

    fflush( stdout );  
    fclose( DataFile );
}
```

Complete linux verified and working C++ example

```
#include <stdlib.h>  
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <unistd.h>

#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    FILE *DataFile;
    DataFile = fopen( "data", "w" ); // open file "data" for writing
    dup2( fileno( DataFile ), 1 ); // exchange "standard output/console" with file "data"

    std::cout << "this goes to 'data' file from c++" << std::endl;

    fflush( stdout );  
    fclose( DataFile );
}
```

Comment: It certainly can't work with C++ streams, as it uses POSIX file descriptors, which means it also can't work with Standard C streams.

Comment: @NeilButterworth C++ streams and C streams are using file descriptors internally, so it works at least on Linux (verified).

Comment: Notice things like fileno() are also not part of Standard C or C++.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Yes, it is not C standard. `fileno` is "POSIX 1003.1" standard, and `_fileno` is Microsoft's way of implementing POSIX like functionality.